# Product of exponential of operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

in the context of non-relativistic quantum mechanics I want to show that, for any $A$ and $B$ operators

$$e^{A}e^{B}=e^{A+B} $$

if and only if

$$[A,B]=0$$

I remember my professor told use about looking for a differential equation  but I don't remember the details, and I want to be able to prove it. Brute force the series doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Any hint will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no 'only if' because it is not true:
\begin{align}
e^{A+B} = e^A e^B
\end{align}
does not necessarily imply $[A,B] = 0$.

One can easily find an example of this using matrices. Here's one:
\begin{align}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 2\pi i
\end{pmatrix},
B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 \pi i
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
$[A,B] \neq 0$ but $e^{A+  B} = e^A e^B = I$.

Edit:
Let me help with the if part, using a differential equation as OP desires.
Compute
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(e^{t(A+B)}e^{-tA}e^{-tB}),
\end{align}
and show that it is $0$ if $[A,B] = 0$.

That implies that $e^{t(A+B)}e^{-tA}e^{-tB}$ is independent of $t$. In particular, plugging in $t = 0$ gives $e^{t(A+B)}e^{-tA}e^{-tB} = I$ for all $t$. Then plug in $t = 1$ to get $e^{(A+B)}e^{-A}e^{-B} = I$.

QED.

Comment: I don't think this counterexample is correct: I get exp(A) = I, but I don't get exp(B) = I.

Comment: @ColinMcFaul Actually I get the same as nervxxx. I tried wolfram alpha as well: `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixExp+%28{{0%2C1}%2C{0%2C2+pi+i}}%29`

Comment: @ Colin McFaul then you are doing something wrong. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixExp%5B%7B%7B0%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+2+%5C%5BPi%5D+I%7D%7D%5D

Comment: @nervxxx oh same time!

Comment: @ Michael Brown haha yea I was wondering why my name had turned to Michael Brown. :P Anyway I hope the answer gets upvoted more, not because I want points, but simply because it's... correct. ^^

Comment: +1 because this seems to be true --- but on the other hand I think the OP is implicitly asking about Hermitian operators.

Comment: I am unsatisfied with a citation to a blackbox Wolfram result. But I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: @ Colin McFaul er... ok...... If you must, here's how you would do it: Diagonalize $B$, i.e. write it as $B = S M S^{-1}$, where $M$ is its eigenvalue matrix which  has entries $0, 2\pi i$. Then $e^{B} = S e^{M} S^{-1} = S I S^{-1} = I$ because $e^{0} = e^{2\pi i} = 1$.

Comment: I think the problem is in the differentiation of $e^{tA} e^{tB}$. In what order do you put them? Of course if A and B commute that there is no problem... This is why I deleted my answer, but I will repost it.

Comment: You can also write $e^B = I + B + \frac{1}{2} B^2 + \frac{1}{3!}B^3 + \ldots$. It is easy to see that $B^k = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & (2\pi i)^{k-1} \cr 0 & (2 \pi i)^k\end{array} \right)$. Summing the series, you get $e^B = I$.

Comment: @nervxxx, I was trying to work it out the way Peter Shor has it. My difficulty was confirming that the summation of $(2\pi i)^{k-1}/n!$ goes to zero.

Comment: The Taylor expansion of the exponential function shows $1+ 2\pi i\sum_{k \geq 1} (2 \pi i)^{k-1}/k!  = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Define the function $f(u)=e^{uA}e^{uB}$. If $A$ and $B$ commute, you can take the derivatives of the $f(u)$ as follows:

$$\frac{df(u)}{du}=\frac{de^{uA}}{du}e^{uB}+e^{uA}\frac{de^{uB}}{du}=Ae^{uA} e^{uB}+e^{uA}Be^{uB}$$

$$\frac{d^2f(u)}{du^2}=A^2e^{uA} e^{uB}+2Ae^{uA}Be^{uB}+e^{uA}B^2e^{uB}$$

etc.

Now take the Maclaurin series expansion:

$$f(u)=1+(A+B)u+\frac{1}{2!}(A^2+2AB+B^2)u^2+\ldots=\\
=1+(A+B)u+\frac{1}{2!}(A+B)^2 u^2+\frac{1}{3!}(A+B)^3 u^3+\ldots=e^{(A+B)u}$$

For $u=1$ you get the desired result:

$$f(1)=e^{A}e^{B}=e^{A+B}$$

Also check this:

[Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)

[Matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)

Comment: This shows the if but not the only if...

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of trying to find a differential equation to prove this; I've only done by brute forcing the series expansion. That isn't as bad as it sounds. On the one side of the equation you get a single infinite series with terms of $(A + B)^n$. The other side of the equation gives you two infinite series multiplied together, with terms of $A^m$ and $B^l$. Don't make any assumptions about $[A,B]$ yet, and expand everything out until you have all the terms that contain $AB$ and $BA$. You should find that the constant terms and the terms of order $A$ and $B$ all cancel out, which will leave you with your condition for the commutator.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you are working with operators.

Since

$$e^{A}e^B =(1+\frac{A}{2}+\frac{AA}{3!}+...)(1+\frac{B}{2}+\frac{BB}{3!}+...)$$

and

$$e^{A+B} =(1+\frac{A+B}{2}+\frac{(A+B)^2}{3!}+...)$$.

Try matching the terms up using commutators.

Answer (score 0):

The proof (due to Glauber, given in Messiah) is as follows: consider f(x)= exp(xA)+exp(xB)

differentiate it ---> df/dx= Aexp(xA)exp(xB)+exp(xA)exp(xB)B

```
                  df/dx=f(x)[exp(-xB)Aexp(xB)+B] here we have to take care of the order of operators
                  df/dx=f(x)[exp(1-xB)A(1+xB) + B]  expand exponential
```

df/dx=f(x)[A+x[A,B]+B]

It is easy to check that the solution to this first-order differential equation is one at x = 0 which is given by

f(x)=exp(x[A+B]+1/2*x^2[A,B])

for x=1 and [A,B] =0; you can get the required answer